# How can I use $(SourceDir) in BuildArguments Parameter or set ti to a project property?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

In a part of my project I need the full path of a file.

previously I define a Property in a custom .proj file shown below
    
      
        
            D:\FullPathOfFile\MyFile.cs
        
      
      ....
      ....

when I use msbuild.exe from command line, then I pass simply the parameter value.
but when I use a Build server with more than two build-agent, I don't now how can I pass the parameter value to the .proj file.

when I set the MsBuildArguments to "FullPathOfFile=$(SourceDir)\FullPathOfFile\MyFile.cs" in build definition that's not work.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are not using a relative path?

Comment: yes @Mrhinsh we have some limitation

Comment: no @MichaelNorgren I don't find any